# Webscraping in R with XML Package “Null” error

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the table from HKJC into R.

For url1, it works all the time.

For url2&url3, it works sometimes only and has the error message.
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readHTMLTable’ for signature ‘"NULL"’

For url4, it doesn't work any time.

```
library(XML)
url1 = url1 = "http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/RaceCard/English/Local/20180627/HV/1"
starter = readHTMLTable(url1,which=9,encoding = "UTF-8")

url2 = "http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/Info/meeting/Results/English/Local/20180627/HV/1"
result1 = readHTMLTable(url2,which=4,encoding = "UTF-8")

url3 = "http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/Info/meeting/Results/English/Local/20180627/HV/1"
result2 = readHTMLTable(url3,which=5,encoding = "UTF-8")

url4 = "http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/Racing/DisplaySectionalTime.aspx?RaceDate=27/06/2018&RaceNo=1&All=False"
section = readHTMLTable(url4,which=4,encoding = "UTF-8")
```

I've read many helpful threads related to this topic. However, I felt compelled to post because this problem seems to be unique to this webpage.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/Racing/DisplaySectionalTime.aspx?RaceDate=27/06/2018&RaceNo=1&All=False

seems to simply redirect to

[http:racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/Racing/DisplaySectionalTime.aspx](http://http:racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/Racing/DisplaySectionalTime.aspx)

so maybe that's why it can't read the HTML table from the original URL because it really doesn't exist?